# How to use listview to render huge images?

Tags: android, listview, render

I have a huge image to render (1024x25373p) cut into 99 images of 1024x256p.
I have tried to use a ListView, but without success : it crashes when scrolling, whithout any error (exept one line saying the proccess was stopped).
So, my question is, how do I render this huge image ?

Please note that I have tried to use TileView by moagrius, without success (I can't get it to work with navigation drawer)

Comment: Sir, post code and logcat

Comment: show your item view layout

Comment: You need to do a lot of reading about how to scale images.  Each image needs about 1MB of RAM.  So 99 needs about 99MB!  Even with a large heap, you will not be able to load those.

Comment: You don't really want a listview.  You want a custom view that allows you to scroll and dynamically loads only the tiles needed to draw the current screen.  Probably combined with a LRUCache to cap the amount of memory used by bitmaps while allowing you to keep a few in memory for scrolling.

Comment: @GaurawYadav Sorry, I deleted the code to try other things... I'll try to remake it.

Comment: @GabeSechan And where can I find it ?

Comment: Listen to what Simon & Gabe has to say, they are legends dude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a suggestion ,

1. If this is listview, you may not need such larger size images "1024x256p" . 
   Actual size of your imageView may much for less than that. So its a wastage of 
   heap if you try to load those images directly without some processing.
2. Definitly you need to do some scaling down for your image based on actual size that you need. Nice exapmple and code has been published on the [official doc](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)
3. You need to deallocate memory or clear the all bitmaps which are not  visible on the listview for  particular moment.
4. You can use progressing loader in order to load your images in to the listview. Then loading will be happen based on the scrolling.
5. Also you can define lager heap enable in your manifest though it is not recommended but has to do in highly memory consumable apps.

   android:largeHeap="true"